llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Tengo el siguiente código para un sistema de grafos con LLM, no se logra arreglar y nose porque es el motivo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias <3
I have the following code for a graph system with LLM, it cannot be fixed and I don't know why. I appreciate any help, thank you very much <3
import os
from langchain_community.graphs import Neo4jGraph
from langchain_experimental.graph_transformers import LLMGraphTransformer
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.documents import Document

from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
llm = Ollama(model="llama2")

llm_transformer = LLMGraphTransformer(llm=llm)

os.environ['NEO4J_URI'] = "my_uri"
os.environ['NEO4J_USERNAME'] = "my_username"
os.environ['NEO4J_PASSWORD'] = "my_pswd"

graph = Neo4jGraph()

text = "Luna lunaso fue un renombrado sabio y maestro espiritual de la India del siglo XX, conocido por su profunda realización espiritual y enseñanzas sobre el autoconocimiento. Aquí tienes un resumen de su vida y enseñanzas.Experiencia Espiritual: A la edad de 16 años, Venkataraman tuvo una experiencia de muerte cercana que le llevó a una profunda realización del 'Sí mismo'. Esta experiencia lo transformó completamente, y abandonó su hogar poco después para buscar una vida espiritual."

graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents)

Y sale el siguiente error:
And the following error appears:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents)

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\langchain_experimental\graph_transformers\llm.py:762, in LLMGraphTransformer.convert_to_graph_documents(self, documents)
    750 def convert_to_graph_documents(
    751     self, documents: Sequence[Document]
    752 ) -> List[GraphDocument]:
    753     """Convert a sequence of documents into graph documents.
    754 
    755     Args:
   (...)
    760         Sequence[GraphDocument]: The transformed documents as graphs.
    761     """
--> 762     return [self.process_response(document) for document in documents]

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\langchain_experimental\graph_transformers\llm.py:701, in LLMGraphTransformer.process_response(self, document)
    696 def process_response(self, document: Document) -> GraphDocument:
    697     """
    698     Processes a single document, transforming it into a graph document using
    699     an LLM based on the model's schema and constraints.
    700     """
--> 701     text = document.page_content
    702     raw_schema = self.chain.invoke({"input": text})
    703     if self._function_call:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'


Bienvenido. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Este es StackOverflow en español, no hace falta publicar tus mensajes en dos idiomas. Está [SO] si prefieres publicar en ingllés (sin traducción al español, en ese caso).

Hola, Merlin. Por favor aclara la pregunta; en particular ¿qué significa "arreglar"? ¿qué se espera del código?
